# get action content from controller asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following scenario.

I have Webservice Area and 
two controller

1. User controller -  having `[HTTPPost]` attributed action named `GetUserProfile(string tokenkey)` returns some JSON
2. TestWebService Controller - having action named `GetUserProfile(string tokenkey)` *same

now I want to invoke `User->GetUserProfile` from `TestWebService` controller and I want to use JSON result in my action in `TestWebService` Controller

*Note:to make more understandable:- `TestWebService` Controller is for testing webservice and I'm using `ASP.net MVC 4`

`RedirectToAction` is not useful to me , as I want to get result and post too.

Is there any other idea, or I'm going wrong way,

***Please edit my question title if someone find correct one

Comment: Could you clearly say what do you want to get with it?

Answer (score 0):

You could send an HTTP request to this controller action. This could be easily done using either the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class or the new [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class that was introduced in .NET 4.5.

For example:

```
public ActionResult GetUserProfile(string tokenkey)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var requestUri = Url.Action("GetUserProfile", "User", new { area = "WebService" }, "http");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
            new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("tokenkey", tokenkey) }
        );
        var response = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
        response.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        MyViewModel model = response.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyViewModel>().Result;
    }

    ....
}
```